# OnFormSubmit trigger issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a number of forms that have all been working fine for several months (and years in a few cases).  We're a small school district and I am the only tech.  I built the forms so that teachers can request equipment, ask for help, or ask general questions.  The form is embedded in a google site shared with staff members. Once they submit, an apps script in each spreadsheet collects the form data and emails it to me, so that I do not necessarily have to look it up in the spreadsheet.  This has all worked fine for a long time.  Beginning in the last few days I have been getting error messages (example below), and it appears my onformsubmit triggers have all been lost.

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  var myEmailAddress =  "aUser@mydomain.com" ;
  var myEmailSubject  = "Ask The Tech" ; 
  var replyToAddress = String(e.namedValues['Username']);
  try{
    var message = e.values.join( "][" );
    var hmessage  = "<b>From: </b>" + replyToAddress + "<br>";
        hmessage += "<b>Question: </b>" + e.namedValues['Your Question'] + "<br>";
        hmessage += "<b>When: </b>" + e.namedValues['Timestamp'] + "<br>";
    var advancedArgs = {htmlBody:hmessage,replyTo:replyToAddress};
    MailApp.sendEmail(myEmailAddress, myEmailSubject, message, advancedArgs)  ;
  }
  catch(err){
    MailApp.sendEmail(myEmailAddress, myEmailSubject, err)  ;   
  }
}
```

---

```
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
2/1/13 2:30 PM  onMyFormSubmit  You do not have permission to call getActiveSpreadsheet formSubmit  2/1/13 2:30 PM
```

As you can see from the example script, none of the scripts directly call getActiveSpreadSheet, so I don't understand why I am getting this message.  Additionally, once I looked at the script, and realized the triggers were gone, when I added a new trigger, the script started working again onformsubmit, however I STILL get the error messages delivered to my mailbox, as well as the script-generated email.

Is this issue related to the recent forms revamp, something deficient in my code, or is there anything I can do about it?  If it's a google bug, is there an issue tracker I should submit my problem to? Thanks in advance for any responses!

Comment: it seems that you are not the only one who is having this issue. Could you try to add SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() in your script and run it once in the script editor to get the authorization panel for spreadsheet service ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and confirmation that it's not only me.  I tried assigning SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet() to a variable at the top of the function, and then ran the script in the editor, but it did not ask for authorization, and failed then with a type error on the first hit of 'namedValues' (as you would expect when running in the editor). I also then tried submitting a new form response, and the results were the same as before(got the email the code generates, but also got the error message).

Comment: Issue tracker: https//code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list

Comment: An [issue has been submitted](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2391)

Answer (score 1):

[Issue 2391: Since Forms Refresh Update On-Submit Error](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2391)  was reported fixed Feb 25, 2013.